# indexPath returns null for Custom UISwitch in tableView cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

So technically it's not a UISwitch, but rather a UIView with a custom class that behaves just like a UISwitch (https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch)

I'm using this DCRoundSwitch on every row of a table. I want to get the indexPath of the row the DCRoundSwitch is on but it keeps returning null.

Here is how the DCRoundSwitch is configured (uses Value Changed):

[image: Tied Events]

Here's my togglePublic method:

```
-(void)togglePublic:(UIControl *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    DCRoundSwitch *switch1 = (DCRoundSwitch *)button;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)switch1.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSLog(@"PUBLICSWITCH PRESSED %@", indexPath);


    //NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:[[[event touchesForView: button] anyObject] locationInView: self.tableview]];


    if ( indexPath == nil ){

        return;

    }


    AHBContact *contact = [self.contacts[indexPath.section] allValues][0][indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Public switch toggled for: %@", contact);


}
```

As you can see, the indexPath returns nil as the if statement always returns the method before we get to the "Public switch toggled for:" log message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure switch1.superview is actually returning the cell like you are assuming here.

Sometimes you will get odd layers of parent views that you did not expect.

Comment: good idea. what's a good/quick way to check what it's returning?

Comment: nvm. got it -- you were right! it was one child lower than expected.